# Regex - find all links in a tweet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

My regex is poor and letting me down so some help would be great here.

All I want to do is return all the links which appear in a tweet (just a string) - Some examples are:

`"Great summary http://mytest.com/blog/post.html (#test)`

`"http://mytest.com/blog/post.html (#test)`

`"post: http://mytest.com/blog/post.html"`

It should also support multiple links like:
`"read http://mytest.com/blog/post.html and  http://mytest.com/blog/post_two.html"`

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Ben

Comment: It depends how specific you want to get. Perhaps posting the regex you used, and the cases you are not catching might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+\b/`

Update:

To catch links beginning with "www." too (no "http://" prefix), you could try this:

`/\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+\b/`

Comment: I think you can post links in tweets without the http(s). So this will fail something like "I really like www.this-site.com."

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Good comment. I updated my answer to detect links starting with "www." too.

Comment: Ok, now how about "Wow, stackoverflow.com is great!"? :P

Comment: Yea to Andrei's comment:  If you're going to go so far as to worry about starting without http:// you should just check for the non-space characters before all TLDs

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet from a site I wrote that parses a twitter feed. It parses links, hash tags, and twitter usernames. So far it's worked fine. I know it's not Ruby, but the regex should be helpful.

```
if(tweetStream[i] != null)
                    {
                        var str = tweetStream[i].Text;
                        var re = new Regex(@"http(s)?:\/\/\S+");
                        MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(tweetStream[i].Text);

                        foreach (Match m in mc)
                        {
                            str = str.Replace(m.Value, "<a href='" + m.Value + "' target='_blank'>" + m.Value + "</a>");
                        }
                        re = new Regex(@"(@)(\w+)");
                        mc = re.Matches(tweetStream[i].Text);
                        foreach (Match m in mc)
                        {
                            str = str.Replace(m.Value, "<a href='http://twitter.com/" + m.Value.Replace("@",string.Empty) + "' target='_blank'>" + m.Value + "</a>");
                        }
                        re = new Regex(@"(#)(\w+)");
                        mc = re.Matches(tweetStream[i].Text);
                        foreach (Match m in mc)
                        {
                            str = str.Replace(m.Value, "<a href='http://twitter.com/#search?q=" + m.Value.Replace("#", "%23") + "' target='_blank'>" + m.Value + "</a>");
                        }
                        tweets += string1 + "<div>" + str + "</div>" + string2;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this one [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126191109/http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx)

```
^(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is from 2009, but Twitter's API now returns URLs (and expands t.co links).