# How to replace long links to the short?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote callback filter that cuts the long links. But it does not replace long links on short.

Question. How to replace long links to the short?

my code:

```
def short_part_of_link
  links = URI.extract(body)
  link = links.collect { |link| truncate(link, length: 30) }
  self.body << link.map(&:inspect).join(', ')
end
```

test:

```
 dsfs df http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416544/regex-find-all-links-in-a-tweet fsdfds fds fds f  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416544/regex-find-all-links-in-a-tweet      "http://stackoverflow.com/qu...", "http://stackoverflow.com/qu..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short solution is:

```
def short_part_of_link
  body.gsub! %r{http://\S+}, {|link| truncate(link, length: 30)}
end
```

This will update the body by replacing all the words starting with "http://" by their truncated version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also explore [Shortener](https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener) .

Comment: Thanks, it not that was necessary for me, but all the same thanks.